# Are explicit row locks necessary when performing concurrent cascading update queries on overlapping sets?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, locking, mariadb

I have tree data structures which I store in the following tables:

```
#stores the actual node data
CREATE TABLE nodes(
    nodeId MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nodeType VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, #'leaf', 'parallel' or 'sequential'
    nodeValue MEDIUMINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (nodeId) 
);

#stores the parent/child relationships
CREATE TABLE parents(
    nodeId MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
    parentId MEDIUMINT NULL, # null if it is the root node
    PRIMARY KEY (nodeId),
    INDEX (parentId),
    FOREIGN KEY (nodeId) REFERENCES nodes(nodeId),
    FOREIGN KEY (parentId) REFERENCES nodes(nodeId)
);
```

The nodes in the tree can be of three types, `'leaf'` nodes are the leaf nodes of the tree and users can set arbitrary values on them at anytime, `'parallel'` and `'sequential'`nodes can only be branch nodes, a `'parallel'` node's values must always be equal to the `max(value)` of their immediate child nodes, a `'sequential'` node's values must always be equal to the `sum(value)` of their immediate child nodes. Users can also toggle branch nodes from `'sequential'` to `'parallel'` and vice versa. All of these actions must have their changes cascade back up the tree so the data is always consistent. I have some stored procedures to do this (below) but I was concerned that it may not be possible to guarantee that concurrent changes are made correctly.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS setLeafNodeValue;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE setLeafNodeValue(id MEDIUMINT, val MEDIUMINT)
proc:BEGIN
    # assume validation checks to ensure it exists and is a leaf node have already been done
    DECLARE currentNodeId MEDIUMINT DEFAULT id;
    DECLARE currentNodesNewValue MEDIUMINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE currentNodesOldValue MEDIUMINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE currentNodeType VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE prevNodesOldValue MEDIUMINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE prevNodesNewValue MEDIUMINT DEFAULT 0;

    START TRANSACTION;

        WHILE currentNodeId IS NOT NULL DO

            SELECT nodeType, nodeValue INTO currentNodeType, currentNodesOldValue FROM nodes WHERE nodeId = currentNodeId;

            CASE currentNodeType
                WHEN 'leaf' THEN
                    SET currentNodesNewValue = val;
                WHEN 'parallel' THEN
                    SET currentNodesNewValue = (SELECT MAX(n.nodeValue) FROM nodes n JOIN parents p ON n.nodeId = p.nodeId WHERE p.parentId = currentNodeId);
                WHEN 'sequential' THEN
                    SET currentNodesNewValue = currentNodesOldValue + (prevNodesNewValue - prevNodesOldValue);
            END CASE;

            IF currentNodesNewValue = currentNodesOldValue THEN
                COMMIT;
                LEAVE proc; #no change is being made
            END IF;

            UPDATE nodes SET nodeValue = currentNodesNewValue WHERE nodeId = currentNodeId;

            SET prevNodesOldValue = currentNodesOldValue;

            SET prevNodesNewValue = currentNodesNewValue;

            SELECT parentId INTO currentNodeId FROM parents WHERE nodeId = currentNodeId;

        END WHILE;

    COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS setBranchNodeType;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE setBranchNodeType(id MEDIUMINT, newNodeType VARCHAR(10))
proc:BEGIN
    # assume validation checks to ensure it exists and is a branch node have already been done
    # and that newNodeType is either 'parallel' or 'sequential'
    DECLARE currentNodeId MEDIUMINT DEFAULT id;
    DECLARE currentNodesNewValue MEDIUMINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE currentNodesOldValue MEDIUMINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE currentNodeType VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE prevNodesOldValue MEDIUMINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE prevNodesNewValue MEDIUMINT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT nodeType, nodeValue INTO currentNodeType, currentNodesOldValue FROM nodes WHERE nodeId = currentNodeId;

    IF currentNodeType = newNodeType THEN
        LEAVE proc;
    END IF;

    START TRANSACTION;

        CASE newNodeType
            WHEN 'parallel' THEN
                SET currentNodesNewValue = (SELECT MAX(n.nodeValue) FROM nodes n JOIN parents p ON n.nodeId = p.nodeId WHERE p.parentId = currentNodeId);
            WHEN 'sequential' THEN
                SET currentNodesNewValue = (SELECT SUM(n.nodeValue) FROM nodes n JOIN parents p ON n.nodeId = p.nodeId WHERE p.parentId = currentNodeId);
        END CASE;

        UPDATE nodes SET nodeType = newNodeType, nodeValue = currentNodesNewValue WHERE nodeId = currentNodeId;

        IF currentNodesNewValue = currentNodesOldValue THEN
            COMMIT;
            LEAVE proc;
        END IF;

        SET prevNodesOldValue = currentNodesOldValue;

        SET prevNodesNewValue = currentNodesNewValue;

        SELECT parentId INTO currentNodeId FROM parents WHERE nodeId = currentNodeId;

        WHILE currentNodeId IS NOT NULL DO

            SELECT nodeType, nodeValue INTO currentNodeType, currentNodesOldValue FROM nodes WHERE nodeId = currentNodeId;

            CASE currentNodeType
                WHEN 'parallel' THEN
                    SET currentNodesNewValue = (SELECT MAX(n.nodeValue) FROM nodes n JOIN parents p ON n.nodeId = p.nodeId WHERE p.parentId = currentNodeId);
                WHEN 'sequential' THEN
                    SET currentNodesNewValue = currentNodesOldValue + (prevNodesNewValue - prevNodesOldValue);
            END CASE;

            IF currentNodesNewValue = currentNodesOldValue THEN
                COMMIT;
                LEAVE proc;
            END IF;

            UPDATE nodes SET nodeValue = currentNodesNewValue WHERE nodeId = currentNodeId;

            SET prevNodesOldValue = currentNodesOldValue;

            SET prevNodesNewValue = currentNodesNewValue;

            SELECT parentId INTO currentNodeId FROM parents WHERE nodeId = currentNodeId;

        END WHILE;

    COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Would the default row locking within the transactions of my stored procedures guarantee that if two separate changes resulted in the same nodes being updated simultaneously (for example the root node of the tree will always be updated by every change) that one set of changes would be applied before the following set of changes were calculated and applied, or would I need to explicitly set locks on all the node rows making up the parent lineage that was going to be changed before making changes to those rows?

## Example:

(p)-parallel, (s)-sequential
tree with node values:

```
(p)4
|
|__(s)3
|   |
|   |__1
|   |
|   |__2
|
|__(p)4
    |
    |__3
    |
    |__4

#this test data can be seeded with
INSERT INTO nodes (nodeType, nodeValue) VALUES ('parallel', 4), ('sequential', 3), ('parallel', 4), ('leaf', 1), ('leaf', 2), ('leaf', 3), ('leaf', 4);
INSERT INTO parents (nodeId, parentId) VALUES (1, null), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 3), (7, 3);
```

If one user changes the `1` value to a `3` and another user sets its parent `(s)3` to `parallel`, then the end result should be:

```
(p)4
|
|__(p)3
|   |
|   |__3
|   |
|   |__2
|
|__(p)4
    |
    |__3
    |
    |__4
```

but if the order the changes are applied to the node rows is not guaranteed it could result in the root node having the value `(p)5` if it was calculated in some Intermediary state. It doesn't matter which change gets processed first, only that they are processed in a way that ensures they don't overlap and interfere with each other as they both cascade up the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation I think the answer is that I would need to use additional locks to ensure the behavior is correct. I believe I would need to:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
SET autocommit=0;
```

before my `START TRANSACTION;` statement in order to lock the lineage of nodes being updated in a given change, and prevent other concurrent executions of these stored procs from clashing with each other. This way all the `SELECT` statements get implicitly converted to `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` and they will wait until any existing overlapping lineage operations have been fully completed. However this shouldnt prevent other simple reads from reading the nodes whilst an update is going on.

so the `setLeafNodeValue` sp will look something like:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS setLeafNodeValue;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE setLeafNodeValue(id MEDIUMINT, val MEDIUMINT)
proc:BEGIN
    # assume validation checks to ensure it exists and is a leaf node have already been done
    DECLARE currentNodeId MEDIUMINT DEFAULT id;
    DECLARE currentNodesNewValue MEDIUMINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE currentNodesOldValue MEDIUMINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE currentNodeType VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE prevNodesOldValue MEDIUMINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE prevNodesNewValue MEDIUMINT DEFAULT 0;

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
    SET autocommit=0;
    START TRANSACTION;

        WHILE currentNodeId IS NOT NULL DO

            SELECT nodeType, nodeValue INTO currentNodeType, currentNodesOldValue FROM nodes WHERE nodeId = currentNodeId;

            CASE currentNodeType
                WHEN 'leaf' THEN
                    SET currentNodesNewValue = val;
                WHEN 'parallel' THEN
                    SET currentNodesNewValue = (SELECT MAX(n.nodeValue) FROM nodes n JOIN parents p ON n.nodeId = p.nodeId WHERE p.parentId = currentNodeId);
                WHEN 'sequential' THEN
                    SET currentNodesNewValue = currentNodesOldValue + (prevNodesNewValue - prevNodesOldValue);
            END CASE;

            IF currentNodesNewValue = currentNodesOldValue THEN
                COMMIT;
                SET autocommit=1;
                LEAVE proc; #no change is being made
            END IF;

            UPDATE nodes SET nodeValue = currentNodesNewValue WHERE nodeId = currentNodeId;

            SET prevNodesOldValue = currentNodesOldValue;

            SET prevNodesNewValue = currentNodesNewValue;

            SELECT parentId INTO currentNodeId FROM parents WHERE nodeId = currentNodeId;

        END WHILE;

    COMMIT;
    SET autocommit=1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```